# Scala Spark to create multiple columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a pyspark function but would need to convert that to Scala

PySpark

```
for i in [c for c in r.columns if c.startswith("_")]:
            r = r.withColumn(i, F.col(i)["id"])
```

As scala data type is unmutable hence any better way from Scala for me to create multiple new columns ,without val df1 = df.withcolumn, val df2 = df1.withcolumn like what I did in pyspark ?

Table r as below

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|         _0|           _1|           _2|           _3|           _4|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|[1, Carter]|   [5, Banks]|[11, Derrick]|    [4, Hood]|    [12, Jef]|
|[1, Carter]|    [12, Jef]|    [4, Hood]|   [5, Banks]|[11, Derrick]|
|[1, Carter]|    [4, Hood]|    [12, Jef]|[11, Derrick]|   [5, Banks]|
|[1, Carter]|    [12, Jef]|   [5, Banks]|[11, Derrick]|    [4, Hood]|
|[1, Carter]|    [4, Hood]|    [12, Jef]|   [5, Banks]|[11, Derrick]|
|[1, Carter]|[11, Derrick]|    [12, Jef]|    [4, Hood]|   [5, Banks]|
|[1, Carter]|    [12, Jef]|[11, Derrick]|   [5, Banks]|    [4, Hood]|
|[1, Carter]|   [5, Banks]|    [4, Hood]|[11, Derrick]|    [12, Jef]|
|[1, Carter]|[11, Derrick]|   [5, Banks]|    [4, Hood]|    [12, Jef]|
|[1, Carter]|   [5, Banks]|[11, Derrick]|    [12, Jef]|    [4, Hood]|
|[1, Carter]|   [5, Banks]|    [12, Jef]|[11, Derrick]|    [4, Hood]|
|[1, Carter]|   [5, Banks]|    [12, Jef]|    [4, Hood]|[11, Derrick]|
|[1, Carter]|[11, Derrick]|   [5, Banks]|    [12, Jef]|    [4, Hood]|
|[1, Carter]|    [4, Hood]|[11, Derrick]|   [5, Banks]|    [12, Jef]|
|[1, Carter]|[11, Derrick]|    [4, Hood]|   [5, Banks]|    [12, Jef]|
|[1, Carter]|    [12, Jef]|   [5, Banks]|    [4, Hood]|[11, Derrick]|
|[1, Carter]|    [12, Jef]|[11, Derrick]|    [4, Hood]|   [5, Banks]|
|[1, Carter]|    [4, Hood]|[11, Derrick]|    [12, Jef]|   [5, Banks]|
|[1, Carter]|[11, Derrick]|    [4, Hood]|    [12, Jef]|   [5, Banks]|
|[1, Carter]|    [12, Jef]|    [4, Hood]|[11, Derrick]|   [5, Banks]|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a single select (each `.withColumn` creates a new Dataset to resolve)

```scala
// either replace with the internal id column, or take as is
val updates = r.columns.map(c => if (c.startsWith("_")) col(s"$c.id") as c else col(c))

val newDf = r.select(updates:_*)  // _* expands the Sequence into a parameter list
```

Comment: This is better as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foldLeft

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col}

val updDf = df
      .columns
      .filter(_.startsWith("_"))
      .foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(s"new_$c", col(c).getItem("id")))
```